# I need assistance comparing the year stored in a DateTimeField to the current year and counting the number of items that match

Tags: django, django-models

I have a list of procedures that have a date showing when they are due to be reviewed. I am trying to count the procedure that are due for the current year and display that number on my webpage. (For ex. if I have x number of procedures in my database that are due this year. I would like for them to be counted and have the total number stored in a variable that I can pass to my webpage and display "Procedures needing to be reviewed this year is:  x")

Not sure how to properly extract the year from the DateTimeField and compare to the current year from the datetime.now().year.

Thanks.

I have tried using .count but i get various errors depending on the variable I use. See my code for more explanation of error messages and what I have tried.

```
views.py

        # gets current year and stores it in currentYear.
        currentYear = datetime.now().year

        # opmToReview = posts.objects.filter(reviewYear = 'currentYear').count()  
        # gives error - Cannot resolve keyword 'reviewYear' into field.

        # opmToReview = posts.objects.filter(reviewDue = 'currentYear').count()   
        # gives error - 'currentYear' value has invalid format. 

      #Tried this too but, doesn't work
      # testing for comparing dates
      def opmToReview(request):
         count = 0
         for post in posts
             if currentYear == reviewYear
             count = count + 1
       return render(request, 'opmStatistics.html', {'currentYearReview' : currentYearReview})      



models.py

         class posts(models.Model):
            OPMnumber = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
            title = models.TextField()
            contacts = models.CharField(max_length = 50)
            dateLastReviewed = models.DateTimeField()
            reviewDue = models.DateTimeField()
            status = models.CharField(max_length = 20)
            assignedTo = models.CharField(max_length = 30)
            comments = models.TextField()

            #used to extract the year from reviewDue date
            def reviewYear(self):
                return self.reviewDue.strftime('%Y')



'''



Expected results is the total number of procedure needed to be review for current year.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `reviewDue` is a `DateTimeField`, you can not just pass an integer like `2019` to this. How is the ORM supposed to know that you are looking for the *year* here, and not the number of seconds since January 1, 1970 for example.

You can however use the [**`__year`** lookup [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#year) here:

```
def opmToReview(request):
    currentYear = datetime.now().year
    count = posts.objects.filter(reviewDue__year=currentYear).count()
    return render(request, 'opmStatistics.html', {'count' : count})
```

> **Note**: PEP-8 advices that class names start with an uppercase, and Django advices that model names are singular, so `Post` instead of `posts`. Furthermore PEP-8 says that attributes should be all lowercase with underscores as word separators, so `opm_to_review` and `review_due`.

> **Note**: it is more safe to extract the year *in* the view, since (a) here you use a local variable that can not be set by some view/function/... with side-effects; and (b) if your server is running at at December 31, around 23:59:59, then it will still use the old year one second later until you decide to restart your server.

Comment: Thank you for your help and the link to API.